# Google Maps API v3 - Multiple points with animation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am building a directory of members which as well as listing members either in order of name and distance from a town or city, will display on a map using the Google Maps API v3.

I've got it working almost how I want it, but I am concerned that it's a bit slow. I'm already loading it asynchronously, but there is an issue with the markers.

I want the map to load and then the markers to appear in a drop animation one by one in quick succession. At the moment there is a delay and they all drop together and sometimes they appear on the map and then drop which looks very odd.

I'm using a PHP foreach script (from a MYSQL database) to output the javascript array for the members- there can be anywhere between 10 and 400 markers on the map, but usually no more than 100 at one time.

For brevity I've only included 4 markers in the example below (which as I said before is outputted from a PHP foreach script):

```
<script>
var infowindow = null;
$(document).ready(function () { initialize();  });
function initialize() {
    var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(53.1,-2.2);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: centerMap,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel: false
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    setMarkers(map, sites);
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "loading..."
        });
}

 var sites = [
 ['Joe Bloggs',52.1022,-2.1070,1,"Member &nbsp;<a href=\"#\">Joe Bloggs</a>"],                              
 ['Peter Pan',52.2022,-2.2070,1,"Member &nbsp;<a href=\"#\">Peter Pan</a>"],                                
 ['Andrew Andrewson',52.0322,-2.0170,1,"Member &nbsp;<a href=\"#\">Andrew Andrewson</a>"],                              
 ['Peter Peterson',52.0022,-2.0070,1,"Member &nbsp;<a href=\"#\">Peter Peterson</a>"],  
 ];

function setMarkers(map, markers) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var sites = markers[i];
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: sites[0],
            zIndex: sites[3],
            html: sites[4],
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });

        var contentString = "Some content";
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
}


  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my-key-is-here&sensor=false&' +'callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
```

How can I speed this up and get the markers to appear in a drop animation after the page loads?

Comment: There is no code to delay the plotting of subsequent markers. Use the setTimeout function to add an appropriate delay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TL,DR: [link to demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/128/)

In my opinion, you will have to write custom animation functions to create something slick.

I played around with the out-of-the-box google.maps.Animation.DROP and various `setTimeout` settings and couldn't come up with satisfactory settings. The biggest obstacle seems to be that a handful of marker DROPs happening at once quickly degrades the animation smoothness, resulting in an ugly, choppy, messy rain of markers. It even crashed my IE7 :(

In other words, if you want a good-looking sequence of DROPs, the time delay between successive DROPs needs to be relatively large (100-200 milliseconds), and at 100 markers, that means waiting 10 to 20 seconds until the last marker drops. I think it's far too long to have the end user sit through this whole animation, but if the DROP delays are short, the map's animation does not look good. It's a balance between animation quality and loading speed.

One workaround could be adding a click listener to the map so that when triggered, the remaining undisplayed markers show immediately. I have not added this logic in my demo.

Here's the [**demo on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/128/). There are three variables to play around with, one controlling the number of markers, and the other two controlling the delay between marker DROPs. You may change these values, then click on  <kbd>> Run</kbd>  to view the changes.

Some notes:

1. I sort the random list so that the markers drop from top to bottom. I think it looks better than the scattered rain of markers. You might also rewrite the sort function by distance, so that sites close to a predefined center DROP first.
2. There is a self-executing anonymous function wrapping the timeout, so that new variable scopes are created for each marker.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is just what I need- and I love the way your example sorts to get the animation to go from up to down. I think you are right with getting the delay right. I'm going to try and get no more than 50 at a time, and if there are more than 100 to remove the animation. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You're right, I did not think of disabling the animation when a certain limit is passed. You might also consider an even smaller marker, for these cases, like a dot. I found that a few hundred markers on a small map can get overwhelming.

Comment: Just thought you might be interested in the end result- http://aotos.org.uk/directory/   you can see all the points going down on this link- http://aotos.org.uk/directory/list/singing-teachers/all-areas/by-name/page-1/all-on-one-page/showMap:1/   and you can see it being demonstrated on this video from the launch party at our annual conference- https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=436560903050659 (4min 20 secs in). So, again, thanks for all your help!

Comment: You've been fab. I just had one more question, any idea on how I could integrate map.fitBounds so that the map fits all the markers. Just noticed I've only got fixed zoom and centering on the UK, when it would be good to zoom to fit all markers. Just adding `bounds.extend(siteLatLng);map.fitBounds(bounds);` doesn't work because the markers come after the map.

Comment: @iagdotme I was on vacation so wasn't checking Stack Overflow. If you are still trying to get the bounds to work see the updated jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/283/ you have to put those lines in the right place. As the loop progresses, update the LatLngBounds to include each point, then run `fitBounds` at the end of the loop.

Comment: You are brilliant! Thanks for this. I wasn't sure it was possible, but as you say, it is just getting the right code in at the right places. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If your page is taking long to load, one option you have is to load the Google Maps API asynchronously using a `callback` that may be defined as a parameter on the URL that loads the Google Maps JavaScript library:

```
<script>
window.onload = loadGoogleMaps;

function loadGoogleMaps() {
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src =    
     "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jssensor=false&callback=initialize";
   document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

This will allow you to retain your existing `initialize` function, which will run after the Google Maps JavaScript library has fully loaded, but you will want to remove the call to `initialize()` that is currently within your `$(document).ready` so that it doesn't run twice.

You shouldn't be seeing a two step process where the marker is placed on the map, followed by the `DROP` animation. You may also want to look at how long the `setMarkers` function is taking to run, because if that is taking overly long to run, it could possible be the root cause of what you are describing.

### Edit based on follow up Comment:

One thing that you can use in JavaScript if you would like to create all of your markers, but add a delay between each marker creation is the JavaScript `setTimeout( function, delayInMilliseconds` function. You will have to keep track of where you are in your marker array across calls, but it works will to divide the work into distinct units of work. Using `setTimeout`, you should be able to add a short delay between each marker drop, which should give you the effect your are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am already using a callback in my script (at least I think I am- it looks the same in my script listed above). The page does load quickly, it's just that the Google map takes a while to load. Perhaps this is to be expected with 100+ markers. Perhaps there is no way to speed this process. With regards to the animation, all markers drop together, and it doesn't work very well for 80+ markers. Ideally I'd like them to drop down in sequence. Is this possible?

Comment: You shouldn't be having a problem with 100+ markers; my map has thousands and I don't really start to have problems until I reach ~4K/5K markers. Even in those cases, it doesn't cause the actual map to load slowly, I only see a problem with the time it takes to load and display the actual markers. I have added information about adding a delay in JavaScript to my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

To space the marker creation timewise you could use window.setTimeout(), for example:

```
//UNTESTED!!
            function setMarkers(map, markers) {
                   while (markers.length) {
                    var markerData = markers.shift();
                    window.setTimeout(function(){doSetMarker(markerData,map)},10);// 10 miliseconds. (play with this value).
                    }
                }

                function doSetMarker(markerData,map) {
                    var sites = markerData;
                    var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(sites[1]), parseFloat(sites[2]));
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: siteLatLng,
                        map: map,
                        title: sites[0],
                        zIndex: sites[3],
                        html: sites[4],
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                    });
                        var contentString = "Some content";
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                            infowindow.open(map, this);
                        });

                }
```

Comment: I think this is the right idea. Unfortunately it results in only one marker- the last one. I have a feeling this is because it's outputting the last one multiple times. I see in the above example that the variable `marker` is set a few times and I'm wondering if this is conflicting with something. I also had to change the function `doSetMarker(marker)` to `doSetMarker(map,marker)` so that the function could use the `map` variable. Any ideas?

Comment: You're correct in that the var marker was set too many times and in most cases it doesn't hold a marker anyway, so I changed that, but I don't think there were any conflicts with it. I'll have to build a page and give it a real try in order to come up with something new. I might be able to do that tomorrow. cheers.